# ImportError: cannot import name pubnub

Tags: python, pubnub

i have problem with pubhub module in python 2.7.6.

I've installed by `sudo pip install pubnub`

Output:

```
>>> import pubnub
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "pubnub.py", line 3, in <module>
    from pubnub import Pubnub
ImportError: cannot import name Pubnub

>>> from pubnub import Pubnub
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "pubnub.py", line 3, in <module>
    from pubnub import Pubnub
ImportError: cannot import name Pubnub
```

I reinstalled requests, python-dev and pubnub. Nothing helped

In help('modules') there is module pubnub

Comment: Do you have more than one python installation especially, do you have anaconda installed?

Comment: Only 2.7.6. Anaconda is not installed

Comment: I recommend to remove all pubnub data and do a "pip install pubnub" again

Comment: Are you sure `python3` isn't installed? This generally is an issue that comes up when there is more than one version of python installed.

Comment: You could try and [use Ably](https://github.com/ably/ably-python) instead :)  Shameless self-promotion!

Answer (score 2):

for version 4 of pubnub the instantiation has changed,

```
from pubnub import pubnub
pnconf = pubnub.PNConfiguration()
pnconf.subscribe_key = 'demo'
pnconf.publish_key = 'demo'

pubnub = pubnub.PubNub(pnconf)
```

for more information read their documentation [v4 upgrading for pubnub](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/python/upgrading-v4)

Answer (score 1):

You have a file in your project called `pubnub.py`, which the importer is finding before your installation of the pubnub module, I think.  Rename your file to something else, and everything should work.

Answer (score 1):

I renamed file, removed python3(it was installed still :D), and removed every *.pyc files and it is working for now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem on my Raspberry Pi 3. It ended up being a very silly issue! I had a file called pubnub.py which is why when I ran my script when it was located in the folder "Desktop" it didn't work. However, after I brought it up to its parent directory "pi" it imported pubnub without an issue!